# Running Ubuntu 19.04 on Hyper-V - keyboard drops when running Chromium

Tags: keyboard, 19.04, chromium

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on Hyper-V with the Hyper-V Quick Install option.  All has been good.  I installed Chromium and when I run it, all keyboard input is lost (regardless of window).  If I shut down Chromium keyboard input returns.  Start it up again and keyboard input is gone...you get the idea.

This is a weird one for me...not really sure where to start and I can't find something similar on the forums.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.